# How to assign old leads to a new particular record type in Enterprise Edition(EE)

Tags: apex, data-loader, leads, dataloader.io

I am new to sfdc. i want to assign old leads means leads created before record type is created.so,I want to assign these old leads to a new particular record type.I had tried to assign using dataloader in My developer org.I will update successfully. When i am trying to do that in my production org.It doesn't went successfully.i had created a lead process and record type in my production org.And i created a Lead.When i am trying to export data from dataloader.But i didn't get **RecordtypeId** field in dataloader.

Thanks in davance

Comment: use `RecordType` instead of `recordId`.

Comment: i type wrong i had RecordType id only..But it is not available in fields list.Do you have any idea on this @Tushar Sharma

Comment: did you enable that field also can you access them on standard record creation process?

Comment: i enable that field.It shows recordtypeid name in standard record creation process.But i didn't get any recordtype id in dataloader fields @Tushar Sharma

Comment: Check on the user profile, that does user has access to this record type.

Comment: yes i am the user i had access to that record type.I had tried this in developer org it works.But it EE it is not working..@Salesforcesmarty

Answer (score 0):

When you will be importing through data loader. Give record type value in your csv sheet. Then from salesforce field select record type id and check lookup via checkbox.

A drop down will appear > select Record type name from it.

Thus, you will be able to import it successfully.

Note : While giving the record type name in excel be careful of giving the record type name instead of label. For excample - if you record type name is 'abc xyz' you will give it as 'abc_xyz'.

Thanks.

Comment: i had created a few records with record type in my organisation.When i am try to query those records with id & record-type id.In query fields record-type is not avliable. I had done this in developer org it done successfully. so now i am  trying to do it workbench i don't know why it is not working with dataloader @Heena